# Unix command to display search pattern and its count

Tags: unix

I am running a test and the servers are Unix machines.
Can anyone share a simple command to display the output that should look like:

```
"ORA-1234" - 100
```

Answer (score 1):

use the grep command

```
grep -i ORA-1234 your_output_file_name | wc -l
```

Comment: The `-i` option is for case-insensitive patterns, isn't it?  If so, how does this count the number of appearances?

Comment: thanks for your comment I added wc -l  to the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "ORA-1234 $(grep -c ORA-1234 $input_file)"
```

This uses `grep -c` to count how often `ORA-1234` appears in the input file.

Generalizing:

```
for pattern in ORA-1234 ORA-2345 ORA-3456
do
    echo "$pattern $(grep -c $pattern $input_file)"
done
```

If spaces in file names are an issue, you can deal with it slightly differently:

```
echo $pattern $(grep -c $pattern "$input_file")
```

Etc.

If you're adamant about wanting the double quotes and dash, then:

```
echo '"'$pattern'" -' $(grep -c "$pattern" "$input_file)
```

If you don't absolutely need the pattern echoed in the output, you can do without the `echo` and `$(...)` command substitution:

```
grep -c "$pattern" "$input_file"
```